# The "Review your question" button is not activated

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, user-interface

It happened on classic "Stack Overflow" which was about coding. I don't even know how to comment it. Here is an image:

[image]

The "Next" buttons have been pressed too. How can I submit the question in this situation?

Comment: I can confirm that there seems to be a bug with showing related questions. If you enter tags, then click next, nothing is happening. When you then edit the tags again (remove and readd one of the tags), a widget "Do any of these posts answer your question" pops up.

Comment: @BDL, Yes i was seen it too, when redacted tags for refreshing.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem you report here, but when you do review your question, please pay attention to proper capitalisation of "I" and instead of just hand waving "I looked at things on the internet" you should detail out which things exactly you tried.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I didn't did this because information, which needs to be written in "`What are the details of your problem?`" section, will be dupicated. So, i was think to just explain in-short this things, but if it's so needed and if it's normal to duplicate this part of explaining, then ok.

Comment: Wondering btw how you managed to select this `[information]` Tag visible on your Screenshot, ... as it doesn't seem to exist (on 'SO-Main')...!?

Comment: @chivracq, Yes, i chose it without knowing that it can't be added by me. But system notified me about that only after i clicked on "Submit" button.

Comment: What is *'classic "Stack Overflow"'*? The original English Stack Overflow (in contrast to [Добро пожаловать на сайт «Stack Overflow на русском»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour))?

Comment: Yeah. This question here on meta is there about the very real and severe bug on SO preventing people from asking questions. There is nothing to agree or disagree about. "I don't agree that you are having this problem" is nonsense. As for the quality of the question to be posted itself, maybe wait with judging it before the OP has actually gotten a fair chance to review it themselves?

Comment: This issue should now be fixed.

Answer (score -14):

After I clicked on the drop-down list "Do any of these posts answer your question?", it was hidden and after that a button with a check-mark had been shown.

---

I think it's a bad idea to add this drop-down list only in this situation, because I found this solution accidentally.