# Cannot publish/review question on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug

I tried introducing my colleague to Stack Overflow, on the 8th of December 2022, so he could post hist first question. The ask wizard is enabled for him and he cannot deactivate it. Unfortunately, the button to "Review your question" is grayed out and he cannot publish his first question.

Are there any workarounds until a fix is applied?

Comment: Indeed the question is similar, but it is quite downvoted and no accepted answer is provided. Removing a tag does indeed make a widget of "Do any of these posts answer your question" pop up, but the button is still grayed out.

Comment: Questions on meta work a bit differently, you don't need an answer for them to be duplicates. Also this would be easier for the developers since they won't need to look at the same bug twice.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, Ah ok Understood. Wouldn't it hinder the devs if the original post is a bit chaotic? There seems to be a fight about grammar use between people.

Comment: Is this a good conclusion of the similar post to mine? There are no apparent workarounds; only a fix can solve this issue that has already been reported.

Comment: A post closed yesterday: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384515/282094 had this cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421937/3648282

Comment: @Imad The post is probably heavily downvoted due to the poster's etiquette rather than the Q/A itself